# Sending Data to a Server with Jquery (Ajax) and PHP and GET the Data

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i am trying to get a Website done. The Problem is: I dont know how i can send the Data to the Webserver and save the data at is place. What i have is some ul´s where i can drag and drop li´s with ids (user_0 to user_100). What I want is to click on the submit button and send the Data as it is to the server and save the changes but that is the point where i am stuck. Maybe you can help me out:

```css
  * {
            font-family: 'Fredoka', sans-serif;
            font-family: 'Gothic A1', sans-serif;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
            font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }


        #sortable1, #sortable2 {
          border: 1px solid #eee;
          width: 400px;
          min-height: 20px;
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 5px 0 0 0;
          float: left;
          margin-right: 10px;
        }
        #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
          margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
          padding: 5px;
          font-size: 1.2em;
         }
        .unsortiert {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 2%;
            padding: 20px;
            background: #eee;
            }
        .header {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .ui-state-default {
            padding:10px;
            background:#bada55;
            border:1px solid;
            display:inline-block;
            margin:25px
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@300&family=Gothic+A1:wght@200;500&family=Lato:wght@300&family=Nanum+Gothic&family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<style>
      
        </style>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
          $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, tbody").sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>

       
<?php

$sequenz = array(
    array('User' => '1','Name' => 'Test1','farbe' => 'grün'),
    array('User' => '2','Name' => 'Test2','farbe' => 'grün'),
    array('User' => '3','Name' => 'Test3','farbe' => 'grün'),
    array('User' => '4','Name' => 'Test4','farbe' => 'grün'),
    array('User' => '5','Name' => 'Test5','farbe' => 'grün'),
    array('User' => '6','Name' => 'Test6','farbe' => 'grün'),
);

?>
    <?php
echo '<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">';
    foreach ($sequenz as $result) {
        echo '<li id="user1" class="ui-state-default">' . $result['Name'];
    }
echo '</ul>';
?>


<?php
echo '<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">'. "Tabelle2";
echo '</ul>';
?>




<?php
echo '<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">'. "Tabelle2";
echo '</ul>';
?>

    <button class="submit">Hier klicken zum Speichern in der Datenbank</button>

<script>
$('#sortable1 li').attr('id', function() {
  return 'name' + $(this).index();
});
</script>


<script>


</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stuck how exactly? Do you know how to use AJAX to send a request? Do you know how to write jQuery code to handle the user clicking on something? Please clarify the specific problem, and what you've researched and tried so far in order to solve it. We're happy to help you if there's a clear question which hasn't been answered before, but we're not a substitute for making your own attempts, or for studying tutorials etc. See also [ask].

Comment: i have tried some things, like toArray() in Jquery and then activate a fetch API. But i dont know how to write it thats the point where i am stuck. I dont understand how i can send the ID´s user_0 to user_100 to an array and use it for the next steps..

Comment: Sorry let's clarify it then, you have some `li`s, and you can move them around. Am I right in thinking that the `li`s have specific IDs associated with them? It's not clear from the code, and not very clear from your description either. And are you saying that, at some time, you want to collect all these IDs from the `li`s and send them to your server? Are you wanting to send something extra with that as well, such as the sequence order in which the IDs occur in the list maybe? Give a clear example of the actual HTML (not just PHP code to generate it) and the output you want when submitting